# Get NSEntityDescription from to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a user entity with a to-many relationship called "recordings".

The generated interface looks like this:

```
@interface User : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * display_name;
// ...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *recordings; // <-- this one
@end

@interface User (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addRecordingsObject:(Recording *)value;
- (void)removeRecordingsObject:(Recording *)value;
- (void)addRecordings:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeRecordings:(NSSet *)values;
@end
```

I'm keeping this user inside a session object (singleton) which is used throughout the application. To add a recording, I've created a convenience method that will return an empty "Recording" object which can then be populated by the calling code:

```
- (Recording *)newRecording
{
    Recording *recording = [NSEntityDescription 
        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recording" 
        inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    return recording;
}
```

I pass the `@"Recording"` entity name to `insertNewObjectForEntityForName::` and this works fine; however, I don't like that my object knows the actual entity name for its `.recordings` relationship property.

Is there an easy way in which I can say "Create a new object for *this* relationship"?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) and the convenience methods it adds which allow you to ask an `NSManagedObject` subclass for its entity name. This would be the minimal change to your current code.

Otherwise, you'd be using the entity description to get the `relationshipsByName`, using the associated relationship description to get the `destinationEntity` and then you have the `name` that you need. You could add this as a category method so it's easily accessible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use mogenerator, as @Wain suggested, you can mirror its approach. Write a class method on `Recording` to create a new `Recording` that is related to a particular `User`.

In `Recording.h`:

```
+ (Recording *)insertInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc;
+ (Recording *)insertWithUser:(User *)user;
```

In `Recording.m`:

```
+ (Recording *)insertInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc
{
    Recording *recording = [NSEntityDescription 
        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recording" 
        inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    return recording;
}

+ (Recording *)insertWithUser:(User *)user
{
    // an NSManagedObject subclass knows its MOC
    Recording *recording = [self insertInManagedObjectContext:user.managedObjectContext];
    [recording.users addRecordingsObject:recording];

    return recording;
}
```

You'll also want to write a method to search for an existing `Recording` object using whatever uniquing criteria are appropriate (the "find-or-create" pattern), and invoke that method within `+insertWithUser:` instead of always inserting a new `Recording`.